# Add a column in a dataframe which takes the value of a column X if it is not blank , else it takes the value of column Y

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column with data separated by delimiter `"\"`. There could be 1 or 2  delimiters and it varies by row.
I was able to split the column into multiple columns as follows:

```
df[['Desc1','Desc2','Desc3']] = df['Descr'].str.split("\\", expand=True)
```

Now some of the rows in `df['Desc3']` have values and some in `df['Desc1']`. I want to add a column which will take the value in the `Desc3` column if it has a value, and if not then take the value in column `Desc1`.

I tried the following code

```
def fn_name(row):
    if row['Desc3'] == '':
        return row['Desc1']
    else:
        return row['Desc3']

df['name'] = df.apply(fn_name,axis=1)
```

However, this does not work. It returns the `df['name']` column with a value when `row['Desc3']` is not blank, but it does not return it with the value in `row['Desc1']` when `row['Desc3']` is blank.

1. How do I fix this?
2. is there a better way to do this rather than using apply function?

Comment: Please provide some example data, desired output, and actual output. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: I tested your code with a small example. It works. Can you please explain with example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think '' is going to be a problem. '' is not as same as null.

You need to use null instead of '' to check the condition.

There's going to be two solutions.

```py
# using apply
def fn_name(row):
    if pd.notnull(row['Desc3']):
        return row['Desc1']
    else:
        return row['Desc3']

df['name'] = df.apply(fn_name, axis = 1)


# using np.where
df['name'] = np.where(pd.notnull(df['Desc3']), df['Desc3'], df['Desc1'])
```